Why use slice assignment to populate an empty list?
I'm looking at some legacy code operating on complex numbers.  The programmer did something like this simple example:
x=[(1+1j), (2+2j), (3+3j)]
j = []
j[:] = [2**y for y in x]

This is "slice assignment", I believe.  Why do it on an empty list you just created?  It's different from this:
j=[(2**y) for y in x]

but is it "better"?
I'm not going to change it, I just need to understand what the code is doing and why.
I believe this answer does not address the question: What does colon at assignment for list[:] = [...] do in Python

The real alternative is j = [2**y for y in x]. Initializing an empty list and then slice-assigning its contents immediately after is nonsense. We don’t know why someone might do it that way.

<identifier>[] = <expression> is just a syntax error. If you take a look at the grammar you can see that the slice non-terminal just cannot be empty inside an assignment. So the answer is: "because the python devs decided to do it that way"

There is a difference between j = ... and j[:] = ... generally, the first doesn't modify the list that j previously contained, while j[:] = ... does. For example, If you had the same list assigned to two variables (like i = [] ; j = i), doing j = ... wouldn't modify i, while doing j[:] = ... would. But that's moot because j is a brand new empty list in the code you provided, it couldn't be assigned anywhere else

j = ...  never modifies whatever value j might have previously held. It only makes the name j refer to a different value, regardless of whether j was previously defined or not.

This question is similar to: What does colon at assignment for list[:] = [...] do in Python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, my question was buried.  Why create an empty list and immediately do a slice assignment?  Am I missing an important point of what the other programmer did?   That is not addressed in the other question.


j[] = x is just invalid syntax.
j[:] = x (equivalently: j[0:len(j)] = x) replaces the contents of the existing list j so that it becomes a copy of what's in the list x (or any iterable x).
j = x reassigns the variable j so that it now refers to list x (or whatever x is); the original list is unchanged.

So there are two reasons you might want j[:] = x instead j=x:

You want a copy of x, so that later changes to j don't affect x (in that case j = x.copy() or j = copy(x) or j = deepcopy(x) would be more readable). Or you want to copy x so that you get an actual list type from an iterable (in that case j = list(x) would be more readable).
You want to change an existing list, which can be accessed other than through variable j. For example:
j = []
y = j
j[:] = [1, 2, 3]
print(y)
j = [5, 6, 7]
print(y)



will print [1, 2, 3] first (because then y and j refer to the same list, and slice assignment changed its contents) and then it will print [1, 2, 3] again (because the variable j now refers to a different list).
P.S.: Note that the expression j[:] = x is not saying "evaluate j[:], and then assign x to the result", even if it may look like that, that wouldn't really make sense. Internally, it is syntax for the call j.__setitem__(slice(None, None), x), whereas x = j[:] calls j.__getitem__(slice(None, None)) and binds variable x to the result.

1: yes, j[] = x was a dumb mistake

1: I can't see any reason in the remaining code for isolating x, but I see now that a new copy of the data is created, and operating on j leaves x alone.   Maybe he had an unknown reason, but I can comment and note what is going on now.
